# Coverity Prevent 5 for .NET development?

Tags: .net, static-analysis, coverity-prevent

Do you use [Coverity Prevent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverity#Products) or Coverity Prevent 5 with .NET development? If yes, what are your feelings about it?

Comment: Coverity 5 is not yet available.